# Attaching databases of sql 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I have few databses of sql 2000 on windows 2000. Can I attach these databases to another instance of SQL Server 2000 on anothermachine having windows 2003 installed?? Does attach and detach of databases are platform independent??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to attach and detach databases of the same SQL Server version across different Windows OSes.

Comment: Did microsoft has documenteed it anywhere? Can you please provide me any link or document on this

Comment: There is documentation for SQL Server 2005 @ http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794(SQL.90).aspx - couldn't find it in SQL Server 2000 Books Online @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256841(SQL.80).aspx.

I remember trying this years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can detach and re-attach from the same SQL version; however this **can** cause issues so it would be best if you backed up the database from the original server, create a new database on the new server of the same name and then restore it into it.

Windows version shouldn't make a difference.